# Скроллинг блока

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как реализовать следующую задачу: у дива со стилем `overflow: hidden;` надо прокручивать содержимое колёсиком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jquery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html) ВАМ в помощь. Очень удобно и легко

Answer (score 0):

jquery.jscrollpane.js вам в помощь.